# Shader raises RuntimeError: Validation failure (0):

Tags: python, opengl, shader, pyopengl

Depending on the value of `MAX_LIGHTS` the following shader code raises the following exception.  Any idea why this is?  What am I missing?

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenGL/GL/shaders.pyc in compileProgram(*shaders, **named)
    194     program = ShaderProgram( program )
    195     glLinkProgram(program)
--> 196     program.check_validate()
    197     program.check_linked()
    198     for shader in shaders:

/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/OpenGL/GL/shaders.pyc in check_validate(self)
    106                 """Validation failure (%s): %s"""%(
    107                 validation,
--> 108                 glGetProgramInfoLog( self ),
    109             ))
    110         return self

RuntimeError: Validation failure (0):
```

Vertex shader code:

```
#define MAX_LIGHTS 2

varying vec4 diffuse[MAX_LIGHTS], ambientGlobal[MAX_LIGHTS], ambient[MAX_LIGHTS];
varying vec3 normal[MAX_LIGHTS], lightDir[MAX_LIGHTS], halfVector[MAX_LIGHTS];
varying float dist[MAX_LIGHTS];

void main()
{   
    vec4 ecPos;
    vec3 aux;

    for (int i=0; i<MAX_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
        /* first transform the normal into eye space and normalize the result */
        normal[i] = normalize(gl_NormalMatrix * gl_Normal);

        /* now normalize the light's direction. Note that according to the
        OpenGL specification, the light is stored in eye space. Also since 
        we're talking about a directional light, the position field is actually 
        direction */
        ecPos = gl_ModelViewMatrix * gl_Vertex;
        aux = vec3(gl_LightSource[i].position - ecPos);
        lightDir[i] = normalize(aux);

        /* compute the distance to the light source to a varying variable*/
        dist[i] = length(aux);

        /* Normalize the halfVector to pass it to the fragment shader */
        halfVector[i] = normalize(gl_LightSource[i].halfVector.xyz);

        /* Compute the diffuse, ambient and globalAmbient terms */
        diffuse[i] = gl_FrontMaterial.diffuse * gl_LightSource[i].diffuse;
        ambient[i] = gl_FrontMaterial.ambient * gl_LightSource[i].ambient;
        ambientGlobal[i] = gl_LightModel.ambient * gl_FrontMaterial.ambient;


    }
    gl_Position = ftransform();


}
```

Fragment shader code:

```
#define MAX_LIGHTS 2


varying vec4 diffuse[MAX_LIGHTS], ambientGlobal[MAX_LIGHTS], ambient[MAX_LIGHTS];
varying vec3 normal[MAX_LIGHTS], lightDir[MAX_LIGHTS], halfVector[MAX_LIGHTS];
varying float dist[MAX_LIGHTS];


void main()
{
    vec3 n, halfV, viewV, ldir;
    float NdotL, NdotHV;
    vec4 color = ambientGlobal[0];
    float att;

    for (int i=0; i<MAX_LIGHTS; i++)
    {
        /* a fragment shader can't write a verying variable, hence we need
        a new variable to store the normalized interpolated normal */
        n = normalize(normal[i]);

        /* compute the dot product between normal and ldir */
        NdotL = max(dot(n, normalize(lightDir[i])), 0.0);

        if (NdotL > 0.0) {

            att = 1.0 / (gl_LightSource[i].constantAttenuation +
                    gl_LightSource[i].linearAttenuation * dist[i] +
                    gl_LightSource[i].quadraticAttenuation * dist[i] * dist[i]);
            color += att * (diffuse[i] * NdotL + ambient[i]);


            halfV = normalize(halfVector[i]);
            NdotHV = max(dot(n,halfV),0.0);
            color += att * gl_FrontMaterial.specular * gl_LightSource[i].specular * pow(NdotHV,gl_FrontMaterial.shininess);
        }
    }
    gl_FragColor = color;
}
```

Comment: So... where's the rest of the error message? The program info-log?

Comment: That is it.  I am not getting any more error message: `glGetShaderInfoLog` returns an empty string.

Comment: Of course glGetShaderInfoLog returns an empty string; you need to use glGet''Program''InfoLog.

Comment: More importantly, why are you outputting *fourteen separate values* from your vertex shader? Not to mention the fact that over *half* of them can be computed just fine by your fragment shader. Also, the normal *doesn't change* with the light; you only need to write one of them. Some of the "varyings" are *constants* that never change (the colors in particular). Really, what's the point of doing per-fragment lighting if all of the important computations are done in the vertex shader? You already lost most of the advantage of doing per-fragment computations by interpolating the light direction.

Comment: Hum, trying to adapt the examples in the [lighthouse3d tutorial](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/tutorials/glsl-tutorial/spot-light-per-pixel/) to add more than one light source.  Ideally, a point and a spot light which is all I really need.

Comment: Oh... wow. I'm sorry. Those are just terrible practice. And I thought my tutorials encouraged some bad practices; at least I'm not passing constants through varyings...

Comment: ^_~ No problems!  I think I am going to give up on those tutorials and look elsewhere -- should I look at yours?  Do you know of anyone who has a simple point source and spotlight source shader?  It must exist (or not be too hard to write from scratch)...

Comment: Stop looking for shader code to copy. Learn how OpenGL works, learn how lighting works, and you can write your *own* lighting code.

Comment: Yeah, thought you were going to say that.  The problem with that is when I tried, I got a shader that worked on my machine but does not on virtual machines.  So, back to drawing board trying to optimise shaders with very little experience in doing so. Need I say that this is a late project?.... ^_~  Anyhow, thank you for your help.

Comment: @NicolBolas: BTW, if you write up your comments as an answer (cut and paste should be fine), I'll upvote and accept.